# AssertionError when JUnit testing a JSON response

Tags: java, json, spring, junit

I am creating my first unit test, and just wanted to create something pretty simple based on one of the Spring tutorials.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Response content
Expected: (null or an empty string)
 but: was "Debug"
```

My Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/person")
public class PersonController {

  @Autowired
  protected PersonService personService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/lastName", produces = "application/json")
  public String lastName(@RequestParam(value = "cid") String cid)
  {
    return personService.findByCId(cid).getLastName();
  }
```

My Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MvcLastNameTest {

@Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void shouldReturnNonNullString() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/person/lastName?cid=123456")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().string(isEmptyOrNullString()));
  }

}
```

Comment: And what result do you expect?

Comment: From my point of view, you might lack to mock the comportment of your call to personService.findByCId() prior to your test, unless you have to in-memory DB set up for your test, which would mean that for the user with the cid=123456, its last name is "Debug"

Comment: I am really dumb... Please forgive me for my awful question.  Reading ya'lls  comments made me remember that our test user's name is "Tom Debug", so his last name is Debug and it isn't returning Debug because some imaginary JSON debugging I was thinking existed. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your test your are expecting `EmptyOrNullString`, but your controller produces a `lastName`

change your expectation:

```
.andExpect(content().string("Debug")); // or any other valid lastName
```